# Unity Debug.Log not showing in Console app on OS X?

Tags: debugging, unity-game-engine, plugins

I have a simple Unity iOS project, with an object that calls:

Debug.Log("test");

When I run this project in my XCode, I see the output in my XCode console panel, e.g.:

```
MyObject on Start

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 42)
```

But when I run this outside XCode, while using my Mac's Console app to look at the log, I don't see these lines (I do, however, see any native NSLog output).

How can I see Unity's Debug.Log output on an iOS device without XCode?

Note: I can, of course, create a native plugin for NSLog but I think that might be an overkill...

Thanks...

Comment: If, in Xcode, you go to Window>Devices then view the log through there, do you see the debugs then?

Comment: Nope. It's identical to the Console app output